# Matlab ODE45 nonliear must return a column vector

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

```
function yp = nonlinear(t,y)
e=0.2;
yp(1)=y(2);
yp(2) = (-y(1)-e*y(1)^3);
```

code

```
tspan = [0 20];
y0=[0;0]
[t,y]=ode45('nonlinear',tspan,y0)
plot (t,y(:,1))
grid
xlabel('time')
ylabel('u')
title ('u vs. t')
hold on;
```

When I execute this, it says nonlinear must return a column vector. Sorry really noob at this.

```
Error using odearguments (line 90)
NONLINEAR must return a column vector.

Error in ode45 (line 113)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in Project1 (line 3)
[t,y]=ode45('nonlinear',tspan,y0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your initial conditions `y0` is defined as a column vector (notice the `;` in `y0=[0;0]`). You can either:

- change `y0` to be a row vector (`y0=[0,0]`)

OR

- change your function `nonlinear` to return a column vector

as per the code below:

```
function yp = nonlinear(t,y)
e=0.2;
yp = [y(2); -y(1)-e*y(1)^3 ];
```

I would also suggest you pass the function handle to the ode solver:

```
[t,y]=ode45(@nonlinear,tspan,y0)
```

I ran it (in Octave, not in MATLAB), and it works just fine. However, the solution is a flat zero.

But again, as per your previous question, you need to familiarise yourself with MATLAB basics **before** attempting advanced stuff. It's like trying to run before you can walk. See my previous recommendation about tutorials.

Comment: actually I need matlab just for three projects in this class, I wouldn't need it at all during my degree. And this project is due tomorrow, but I really want to thank you for all your help.

Comment: I tried both solutions, neither worked :( any suggestions why?

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work. You need to take a longer-term view of life though, and rather than wait for the last minute to solve your problem and panic, start in advance and get yourself familiar with the tool. You don't know for sure you will not need MATLAB again in your degree, andyou certainly don't know you will not need it in your professional life.